# Is the Golden Raspberry nomination the reason Katie Holmes didn't reprise her role?

Tags: casting, the-dark-knight, batman-begins

I was reading Batman Begins (2005) [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins), and was shocked to see that the movie got [**nominated**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Begins#Awards_and_nominations) for a [Golden Raspberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Raspberry_Awards) award for Worst Supporting Actress for Katie Holmes who played Rachel Dawes in the movie.

We know that Katie Holmes was replaced by Maggie Gyllenhaal in the sequel [The Dark Knight (2008)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dark_Knight_(film)) which had me thinking that it may be because of the said nomination.

So, **was Rachel Dawes role recast because of that nomination?** If so, **was it Holmes' decision or the filmmakers' (producers, director)?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It was Holmes' decision

## It was *not* because of the Golden Raspberry

> Holmes begged off working on the sequel, she says, to pursue other projects, and was replaced in the role of Assistant District Attorney Rachel Dawes by Maggie Gyllenhaal. But that doesn't mean Holmes has any regrets about turning down the project, she insisted.
>
> "Not at all. I had a great experience working with Chris Nolan [and] I'm sure it's going to be a great movie. [But] I chose to do this movie ['Mad Money'], and I'm really proud of it," she told MTV News.

([source](https://web.archive.org/web/20080119151112/http://www.vh1.com/movies/news/articles/1579619/20080114/story.jhtml))

So from Holmes' herself, we are told that it was entirely her decision to leave the franchise to work on something else.

Christopher Nolan has also said he wanted her back, but she wasn't available:

> But Nolan revealed in the lead-up to “The Dark Night” that he had wanted Holmes to return.
>
> “Katie wasn’t available for the role, which I wasn’t very happy about, but these things happen, and I was very, very fortunate that Maggie [Gyllenhaal] was able to take it over,” he said.
>
> Gyllenhaal even personally reached out to Holmes to get her approval to take on the role.

([source](https://www.businessinsider.com.au/why-katie-holmes-left-the-batman-movies-2016-12?r=US&IR=T))

This is also worth reading:

http://www.alloy.com/entertainment/the-dark-knight-director-disappointed-katie-holmes-turned-down-role/#ixzz4S4eIu5rI

Comment: I got to say, though, that it's hard to believe that's the reason after knowing about the Golden Raspberry nomination.

Comment: I think you over-estimate how much people care about the Golden Raspberry.